# FAILED: ParseException line 3:0 cannot recognize input near 'row' 'format' 'demilited' in table row format specification (state=42000,code=40000)

Tags: sql, hive, beeline

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE CLIENTES (
   'idcliente int,
    cnh string,
    cpf string,
    validacnh date,
    nome string,
    datacadastro date,
    datanascimento date, 
    telefone string,
    status string'
 )  
 row format demilited
 fields terminated by ', ' 
 STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Comment: there is a single apostrophe before the parenthesis before row, remove it or iif is not a column add another apostrophe before the comma so that it becomes a string

Comment: Just code and an error message doesn't make a question

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you have the columns as a string literal.  Take out the quotes

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE CLIENTES (
    idcliente int,
    cnh string,
    cpf string,
    validacnh date,
    nome string,
    datacadastro date,
    datanascimento date, 
    telefone string,
    status string
 )  
 row format demilited
 fields terminated by ', ' 
 STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_create_table.htm